# Execute custom sql procedure in MS Master Data Services 2012 Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, master-data-services, mds

My goal is to launch stored procedure from another DB (not MDS DB) when user commits Verion to start ETL process. For that in MDS DB i've added launching custom stored procedure in *[mdm].[udpVersionSave]*.
But when i'm trying to commit Version in MDS Web interface, nothing happens - Version doesn't become commited. BTW, when i launch procedure from MDS DB - it's working.
My guess - the problem is in user\login access. But i try a lot combinations in giving access - nothing helped.

UPD.:
Code which launches stored procedure:

```
execute [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[sp__test_insert_data] @code = N'3';
```

Code of procedure sp__test_insert_data:

```
insert into AdventureWorksDW2012.dbo._test_insert_data(col_ver)
values (@code);
```

Procedure *sp__test_insert_data* works fine, when i'm launching it manually under *sa*.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if we could see the code you've written and what error messages you are getting.

Comment: Added code. No error messages appear while commiting Version.